# How to show image on category page for a specific theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, category-attribute

I am creating a new theme for mobile by copying the "iphone" theme of the "default". There in the category Page I want to **show the image** for the category with description and the list of subcategories.
The Problem is that the uploaded image for the categories is reflected to all the themes. But I want to **show it** in the **"iphone" theme only**.
1.How can I do that ?

2.How can I show the subcategories list with their thumbnail image ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Remove image & description code at location

```
design\frontend\your_packge_name\your_theme_name\template\catalog\category\view.phtml
```

2.Show the subcategories list with their thumbnail image

Follow this : http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html#gref

Comment: hello @Abdul. Should I remove it only those themes where I don't want to show it and keep where I want it ?

Comment: Yes, remove it only those themes where U don't want